# removeEventListener() not working when addEventListener() called with true

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am teaching myself JavaScript and came across a situation where if I call an event listener on both the capture and bubble phases, removing that listener does not work.

```js
function clickHandler(e, objId, num) {
  var obj = document.getElementById(objId);
  obj.innerHTML = "DIV " + num + " says " + " at X position: " + e.screenX;
}

function wrapperOne(e) {
  clickHandler(e, "heading", 1);
  e.target.removeEventListener('click', wrapperOne);
}

function wrapperTwo(e) {
  clickHandler(e, "heading", 2);
  e.target.removeEventListener('click', wrapperTwo);
}

function onloadHandler() {
  document.getElementById("div1").addEventListener('click', wrapperOne, true);
  document.getElementById("div2").addEventListener('click', wrapperTwo, true);
}
```

With this code I can continue to call `wrapperOne` and `wrapperTwo` even after the `removeEventListener` function has been called. If I pass `false` in the `addEventListener` in `onloadHandler` then the event handler does get removed. Could someone explain these two different behaviors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `e.target.removeEventListener('click', wrapperOne, true);`

The third parameter of `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` is the `useCapture` parameter. To be cross-browser supported, you have to specify that boolean on both `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`

Reason why `removeEventListener` worked when you used `false` in `addEventListener` is because `false` is the default value for the `useCapture` parameter.
If you attached an event in the "capture" phase, then you have to tell it to remove the event from the "capture" phase.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener for more information.